Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: Need help in understanding the error
I got this error while compiling a custom javascript runtime project ( i updated some source c++ code and v8 version)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::detail::system_category_instance", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
      boost::asio::io_context::io_context() in main.cpp.o
      boost::asio::detail::scheduler::scheduler(boost::asio::execution_context&, int) in main.cpp.o
      boost::asio::detail::scheduler::~scheduler() in main.cpp.o
      boost::asio::detail::scheduler::~scheduler() in main.cpp.o
      boost::asio::detail::scheduler::shutdown() in main.cpp.o
      boost::asio::local::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::local::stream_protocol>::basic_endpoint(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in main.cpp.o
      ...
  "boost::system::detail::generic_category_instance", referenced from:
      boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(int, std::__1::error_condition const&) const in main.cpp.o
      boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(std::__1::error_code const&, int) const in main.cpp.o
      boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(int, std::__1::error_condition const&) const in module_loader.cpp.o
      boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(std::__1::error_code const&, int) const in module_loader.cpp.o
      boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(int, std::__1::error_condition const&) const in native_module_config.cpp.o
      boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(std::__1::error_code const&, int) const in native_module_config.cpp.o
      boost::system::error_category::std_category::equivalent(int, std::__1::error_condition const&) const in native_module_context.cpp.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am not able to understand the error
Update: This error comes only when i change the c++ standard (to anything other than 11) in my cmake file. Still don't understand how can i resolve it.
How can i resolve this error

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/22708072/833395

@Shivbaba'sson for the same project if i revert to older code and v8 lib file it compiles fine. Additionally i compiled the v8 for x64 systems and executing compilation in rosetta(i386) only

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/q/49815034/833395

Have you followed this link ? https://v8.dev/docs/cross-compile-ios

@Shivbaba'sson these links are not useful for my reference. The issue here is if i change c++ 11 standard in my cmake file i get these linking errors

Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/61317610/833395
